# Add + character as optional parameter into reg exp

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let regex =/^\d{0,9}$/;
```

I have reg exp which have to compare 2 format types(numbers):

```
+3243243
423432423
```

I've created reg exp which will be compare all numbers , but how to also add +  as optional parameter ?

Comment: `\+?` means optional literal plus.

Comment: how to attach it ? can you send reg exp?

Answer (score 0):

Just add an optional + at the start.

```
let regex =/^\+?\d{0,9}$/;
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^+?\d{0,9}$/: Nothing to repeat
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:14
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:74:29)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:182:6)
    at evaluate (/run_dir/repl.js:133:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/run_dir/repl.js:116:5)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
    at fs.read (fs.js:2124:12)

Comment: I've got this error , have you check it ?

Comment: Escaped + try now